# Unable to load pickle object from file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm just trying out the pickle module and learning its functions and utilities. I've written this small piece of code, but it's giving me trouble.

```
import pickle
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\The Folder\\databin.txt", 'r+') #databin.txt is completely blank
class A:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.variable = 25
        self.random = 55
pickle.dump (A, myfile, -1) #HIGHEST_PROTOCOL 
pickle.load (myfile)
```

I then get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
pickle.load (myfile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
```

Comment: You code does not make sense, you can pickle only instances of objects but not a class directly.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to close the file first, then reopen it for that to work; and use binary mode to open your file.

Last but not least, pickle can store *instances* of classes only, not the classes themselves:

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\The Folder\\databin.txt"
with open(filename, 'wb') as myfile:
    pickle.dump(A(), myfile, -1) #HIGHEST_PROTOCOL 
with open(filename, 'rb') as myfile:
    pickle.load(myfile)
```

Here I've used the file as a context manager, it'll close automatically when the `with` suite is exited.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what Martin says is correct.  You need to close the file first, then reopen it.
If you don't you get an error.  I'm using `dill`, instead of pickle, so I can pickle the class.

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 10 2014, 21:37:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> myfile = open('pickle.pkl', 'rb+')
>>> 
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.variable = 25
...     self.random = 55
... 
>>> dill.dump(A, myfile, 2)
>>> dill.load(myfile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py3.3.egg/dill/dill.py", line 187, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/pickle.py", line 847, in load
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Now, close the file, and try again… remember to open it again first.

```
>>> myfile.close()
>>> dill.load(myfile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py3.3.egg/dill/dill.py", line 187, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/pickle.py", line 845, in load
    key = read(1)
ValueError: read of closed file
>>> 
>>> myfile = open('pickle.pkl', 'rb+')
>>> dill.load(myfile)
<class '__main__.A'>
```