# Loading data pickled in linux fails in mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, pandas, pickle

I am saving a python dataset which contains a class, with referenced dictionaries and classes, on a Linux machine. The file loads normally on Windows or Linux, but on mac I get the following error if loading with the 'rb' modifier:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
```

And this error if loading with the 'rU' modifier:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x06
```

Saving and loading were attempted with pickle, cPickle and dill, all with similar outcome.

**Update:**
I am getting this exact error when saving in linux and loading in mac large pandas DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,5)).to_pickle("1.dat")
```

The error recurs when trying to open 1.dat im mac using this code:

```
pd.read_pickle("1.dat")
```

Comment: Which versin of Python do you use in Windows, Linux?

Comment: All are using Python 2.7.8, cPickle v1.71, pickle revision 72223

Comment: can you give a possibly reduced example of what you are pickling that reproduces the error?  that way people can try it easily

Comment: This may be a duplicate question.  You can get a KeyError when you don't close the file properly, as illustrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920792/unable-to-load-pickle-object-from-file

Comment: Thanks. The file was closed properly when this error arose. The class I am pickling holds three dictionaries, where keys are strings and values are classes that do not inherit from object. The mother class has a save method that looks like: 
`def Save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fh:
            cPickle.dump(self, fh)`

Comment: @Korem: Handles to files from python behave differently on different OS. So, in the absence of seeing the code, it's a valid question.

Comment: This is also a possibly related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331901/pickling-error-in-python  Again, would be good to see your code, or a reduced version of it.  Just make an edit to the original question.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: see added information in edit

Comment: So a quick guess is that the issue could be that the **binary** format pickled dataframes are written to a **text** file, and the "newline" on linux is different on each OS (`\n` vs `\r` vs `\r\n`)… and windows may "handle" this newline difference for you, while mac does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was caused after mounting a network linux drive in mac, which caused the insertion of a null character at the end of each large data block transferred thus causing the error.